# why the message property is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I make one controller in Angularjs and try to test that controller using Jasmine. I got this error **Cannot read property 'message' of undefined** why ?

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dplJ6sf4kgiwJ5pXu4GE?p=preview) is my code.

**controller**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app.home').controller('homeCntrl',homeCntrl);

  function homeCntrl(){
    var home=this;
    home.clickbtn=function(){

      home.message='test';
      alert(home.message)
    }
  }
})();
```

**Testing**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  describe('http controller test', function() {

  var $rootScope,
    $scope,
    controller,
    $q,
    $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');

    inject(function($injector) {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $injector.get('$controller')('homeCntrl', {
        $scope: $scope
      })


    })
  })




  describe('Init value', function() {
    it('check name value', function() {
    expect(controller.message).toBeUndefined();  
    })

  })

  it('it should be true', function() {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();

  })
})

})();
```

any update ?durning testing I got this error .. ? can we do testing of this controller ?Every thing is fine on angular js code problem  is on test code..only  check **appspec.js**

Comment: Your html should be `ng-app="app.home"`

Comment: please provide the plunker ?? why ?

Answer (score 1):

Just an hint

app

```
(function() {
'use strict';

function HomeController() {
  var home = this;
  home.title = 'Home';
}

angular.module('home.controllers', [])
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);
})();
```

test

```
'use strict';

describe('home controller', function() {

  var $controller;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('home.controllers'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('HomeController as home', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('should have text = "Home"', function() {
    expect(scope.home.title).toEqual('Home');
  });

});
```

in your case the test should be like

```
scope.home.clickbtn();
expect(scope.home.message).toEqual('test');
```

Take a look at http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/angularjs-unit-testing/ to master unit test in angular